# How to get facebook wall post from a particular user?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

```
$facebook = new Facebook();

$post =  $facebook->api("/APP_ID/users");
```

This method does not works for me..

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried? Where have you failed?

Comment: I dont know that what should be the graph api for a particular user.